# Rails ActiveRecord store and new session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, devise

I am new to Rails and experience a strange issue I don't understand.
I use ActiveRecord as a session store and need to add session id as a property of JSON responses for all the requests. I use Devise as well if it have some impact on the situation. The problem is that if a request is made by a user without cookies (or at least without session id in the cookie) the session.id is empty or - attention, please - not the same value that is set in the response cookie.

For debugging, I add this code as an after_filter to ApplicationController:

```
puts session.id
puts request.session_options[:id]
```

Both values are the same. They match the value in the cookie if it is present. Otherwise, if session id is not present in the cookie, the cookie set after that request has different value.

My opinion is that session_id gets new value after it is actually saved to the database, where it have to be unique. DB migration:

```
def change
  create_table :sessions do |t|
    t.string :session_id, :null => false
    t.text :data
    t.timestamps
  end

  add_index :sessions, :session_id, :unique => true
  add_index :sessions, :updated_at
end
```

My question: How can I get the actual session.id value of a new session before the first response is rendered?

**UPD:**

I just created a new Rails app that uses ActiveRecord session store without Devise, and I can get session.id that is going to be set in cookie just before response with this code id application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_filter :show_session

  def show_session
    puts session.id
  end
end
```

But in my existing app with Devise I get a value that really looks like a session id, but that  doesn't match the value set in the cookie via Set-Cookie response header and the value actually saved to sessions table in database. Looks like Devise have a conflict with ActiveRecord session store in some way. Need to go deeper to figure it out.

**UPD 2**

Looks like I found the problem roots. As I said, I use Devise for authorization with Omniauth. According to the documentation, sign_in method resets session id for security reasons. But after that reset session.id returns the old value, that had been automatically set. I use this code as an Omniauth callback:

```
def facebook_access_token
  sign_in @user
  puts session.id
end
```

And in console I get session id different from the one set in the Set-Cookie response header. If I comment "sign_in" line, these values match. New question: how can I get the new session id value after it is been reset inside of sign_in method? Is it an internal Warden/Devise implementation or something?

Comment: Great question. Same problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I experienced was caused by default Warden configuration. It renewed session id, but somehow the new id was not accessible via session.id.

The only way I found to stop this behavior was putting this code into config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
  auth.env["rack.session.options"][:renew] = false
end
```

Probably this method is not really good for security reasons, but I have no other ideas in a week of searching and reading sources.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but if you are still concerned by this issue, please let me know what you think of my answer

Answer (score 5):

Renewing is still important and you should not disable it

Also the new session id is generated after the execution of the controller, therefore after you have a chance to set the response to be sent to the client.

The solution is to manually trigger the renewing of the session id

In your `ApplicationController` add the method:

```
protected

  def commit_session_now!
    return unless session.options[:renew]

    object = session.options.instance_variable_get('@by')
    env = session.options.instance_variable_get('@env')
    session_id = object.send(:destroy_session, env, session.id || object.generate_sid, session.options)

    session_data = session.to_hash.delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? }
    object.send(:set_session, env, session_id, session_data, session.options)

    session.options[:renew] = false
    session.options[:id] = session_id
  end
```

Then in your controller you just call this method before getting the session id for your response

```
def my_action
  ...
  commit_session_now!
  render json: {session_id: session.id}, status: :ok
end
```

The code in `commit_session_now!` comes from `Rack::Session::Abstract::ID#commit_session` https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L327

Comment: The default behavior is quite counter-intuitive. Any idea why it's done that way? I've noticed the session_id actually gets set twice, once during the request, and then it gets reset during the renew after the request. Is it a middleware ordering issue?

Comment: I haven't look at it for quite a while, but if I remember correctly it's directly related to rack middleware architecture

Comment: @Benj, question: When you do session.options[:renew] = false, what happens to future requests made by the client, to other actions? Is turning off this renew option doesn't create a security hole for future requests? Or is it short-lived, and disable the renew only after we committed the new session id?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of your application, my suggestion would be to use a `before_filter` in your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :use_session_id

  protected
  def use_session_id
    # Do something with session.id 
    # This will get called before any rendering happens
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, sure. But the problem is that if no session id comes in the request, I will get no session.id in the before_filter. I need to get session id that will be generated by Rails to put in the response.

Comment: If there is no session id present in the cookie, then none is sent to the client, unless you reference the `session.id` somewhere in your app. If you reference `session.id` anywhere in your app, it will generate a new session id.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session