# Accessing the new session_id in devise after sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, warden

I am using devise & overriding SessionsController#create to track the login based on a specific condition.

The value of session[:session_id] before sign_in(user) is same even after the execution of sign_in(user).

I would like to store the new session_id in DB in order to track the user. But unable to access it. How to get it?

While looking for it, found that Devise uses set_user method of Warden. But even then, I could not figure out where the session is set in Warden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the following question:

[Rails ActiveRecord store and new session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609844/rails-activerecord-store-and-new-session)

Answer by Benjamin Sinclaire worked for me (though it was not marked as answer). Just replaced session.options with request.session_options