# Tracking the session_id from ActiveRecord::SessionStore after user sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to get the active session_id of a user after the user successfully logs in. The session_id needs to be stored in a field of `User` model for later operations. I'm using `devise` with `activerecord-session_store`.

Tried to override some devise methods after sign_in but didn't help.

Comment: @dbugger yeah that was helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Try this in controller

```
  Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user, auth, opts|
    if (opts[:scope] == :user && opts[:event] == :set_user)
      # code
    end  
  end
```

- you can get session from `session['session_id']`

Reference:
[Ruby on Rails Devise code after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268559/ruby-on-rails-devise-code-after-login/21272314)

Comment: it did not help. session['session_id'] was not accessible in the block. referred to this instead. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609844/rails-activerecord-store-and-new-session
thanks!